# Turing Machine Simulator

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

Write a [Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) simulator.

For simplicity we can assume statuses as integer, symbols as char, blank symbol equals whitespace

5-tuple in the form of current state, input symbol, next state, output symbol, direction (left or right) the order is not mandatory but specify if you swap it

The machine must stop when an unknown state is reached, no other halt condition allowed.

The tape is infinite in both directions and you can always read an empty character.

Input: the initial tape, an initial state and a program. you are free to read the data from anywhere in the format you like

Output: the tape after the execution of the program

Required: an example program that run on top of your simulator

This is a code-colf so the shortest code win.

I'll post an implementation and some example programs in the next few hours.

Comment: [On The Turing Completeness of PowerPoint (SIGBOVIK)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNjxe8ShM-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 92 characters

```
~:m;n\+{:^.n?)>1<]m{2<1$=},.{~2>~^n/~1>[@\+]n*1$%n/~\1$1<+[\1>.!{;" "}*]n*\%@}{;;^0}if}do n-
```

The Turing machine in GolfScript became much longer than intended. Still playing around with different representations of the tape.

First line of the input is the original state, second line the initial tape, followed by an array of transitions (with order current state, input symbol, next state, direction, output symbol).

Example (also [available online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIwCicxMDEnCltbMCAnMCcgMCAxICcwJ10KIFswICcxJyAwIDEgJzEnXQogWzAgJyAnIDEgLTEgJyAnXQogWzEgJzAnIDIgMSAnMSddCiBbMSAnMScgMyAtMSAnMCddCiBbMyAnMCcgMiAxICcxJ10KIFszICcgJyAyIDEgJzEnXQogWzMgJzEnIDMgLTEgJzAnXV0iCgp%2BOm07blwrezpeLm4%2FKT4xPF1tezI8MSQ9fSwue34yPn5ebi9%2BMT5bQFwrXW4qMSQlbi9%2BXDEkMTwrW1wxPi4hezsiICJ9Kl1uKlwlQH17OzteMH1pZn1kbyBuLQ%3D%3D&run=true))

```
> 0
> '101'
> [[0 '0' 0 1 '0']
>  [0 '1' 0 1 '1']
>  [0 ' ' 1 -1 ' ']
>  [1 '0' 2 1 '1']
>  [1 '1' 3 -1 '0']
>  [3 '0' 2 1 '1']
>  [3 ' ' 2 1 '1']
>  [3 '1' 3 -1 '0']] 

110
```

Comment: you beat my sed implementation by one char, time to see if I can do better

Answer (score 8):

## GNU sed with `-r` - <strike>133</strike> <strike>117</strike> <strike>111</strike> 93 chars

Yes, sed is turing complete. GNU sed and `-r` (extended regexps) is only to save a few characters, it is only a small change to work with POSIX sed.

```
:s
s/^(.*@)(.*)>(.)(.*#\1\3([^@]*@)(..))/\5\2\6>\4/
T
s/(..)l>|r>/>\1/
s/>@/@> /
s/>#/> #/
bs
```

Input format is

```
[initial state]@[non-empty tape with > marking head position]#[state]@[input symbol][next state]@[output symbol][direction l or r]#...
```

The delimiters `@`, `#` and head character `>` cannot be used as a symbol on the tape. State labels cannot contain `@` `>` or `#`.

It will run all of the programs in the input, one per line

Examples:

Marco's a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> program

> Input
>
> ```
> 0@>aaabbb#0@a1@ r#0@ 4@ r#1@a1@ar#1@b1@br#1@ 2@ l#2@b3@ l#2@a5@al#3@b3@bl#3@a3@al#3@ 0@ r#4@ 5@Tr
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> 5@    T>  #0@a1@ r#0@ 4@ r#1@a1@ar#1@b1@br#1@ 2@ l#2@b3@ l#2@a5@al#3@b3@bl#3@a3@al#3@ 0@ r#4@ 5@Tr
> ```

Marco's Hello! program

> Input
>
> ```
> 0@> #0@ 1@Hr#1@ 2@er#2@ 3@lr#3@ 4@lr#4@ 5@or#5@ 6@!r
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> 6@Hello!> #0@ 1@Hr#1@ 2@er#2@ 3@lr#3@ 4@lr#4@ 5@or#5@ 6@!r
> ```

Comment: [TIO](https://tio.run/##JYzBCsIwDIbve4pCL6vgsq6bBw8hD7GbdZCiiDA2afXms1ubDUK@fD/8Sffb8bF8cj6nKsFUNwcyZRmsG6H21rv6MtF1yxtjwA@@8yf0PVRjqUg44zcioLdQAiQgVNulAZWGKqScW0JmDiHoltiSioWqF1pxFoYyQtWRmnVHwe3kgXjWTjwI2e2uWumXJwON8be@3s91SfkY/w)

Answer (score 8):

So I'm a bit late, but just thought I would leave this here...

### Turing Machine Simulating a Turing Machine: 370 bytes?

Here I'm using the structure Turing used in his [1936 paper.](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Erobins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf) I'm using one symbol = one byte, including m-configs and operations.

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║    m-config    ║ Symbol ║     Operations      ║ Final m-config ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ currentCommand ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ currentCommand ║
║                ║ *      ║ MR                  ║ readCommand    ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ nextCommand    ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ nextCommand    ║
║                ║ *      ║ E  R  R  R  P* R    ║ readCommand    ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ readCommand    ║ P      ║ R                   ║ readCommandP   ║
║                ║ M      ║ R                   ║ readCommandM   ║
║                ║ G      ║ R                   ║ readCommandG   ║
║                ║ E      ║ R                   ║ MHPNone        ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ readCommandP   ║ 0      ║                     ║ MHP0           ║
║                ║ 1      ║                     ║ MHP1           ║
║                ║ e      ║                     ║ MHPe           ║
║                ║ x      ║                     ║ MHPx           ║
║                ║ None   ║                     ║ MHPNone        ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ readCommandM   ║ R      ║                     ║ MHMR           ║
║                ║ L      ║                     ║ MHML           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ readCommandG   ║ 1      ║                     ║ G2<1           ║
║                ║ 2      ║                     ║ G2<2           ║
║                ║ 3      ║                     ║ G2<3           ║
║                ║ 4      ║                     ║ G2<4           ║
║                ║ 5      ║                     ║ G2<5           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ G2<1           ║ int(1) ║ L  P@ R  R  R  P* R ║ GTS            ║
║                ║ <      ║                     ║ G21            ║
║                ║ *      ║ E  L                ║ G2<1           ║
║                ║ @      ║ E  L                ║ G2<1           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ G2<1           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ G2<2           ║ int(2) ║ L  P@ R  R  R  P* R ║ GTS            ║
║                ║ <      ║                     ║ G22            ║
║                ║ *      ║ E  L                ║ G2<2           ║
║                ║ @      ║ E  L                ║ G2<2           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ G2<2           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ G2<3           ║ int(3) ║ L  P@ R  R  R  P* R ║ GTS            ║
║                ║ <      ║                     ║ G23            ║
║                ║ *      ║ E  L                ║ G2<3           ║
║                ║ @      ║ E  L                ║ G2<3           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ G2<3           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ G2<4           ║ int(4) ║ L  P@ R  R  R  P* R ║ GTS            ║
║                ║ <      ║                     ║ G24            ║
║                ║ *      ║ E  L                ║ G2<4           ║
║                ║ @      ║ E  L                ║ G2<4           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ G2<4           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ G2<5           ║ int(5) ║ L  P@ R  R  R  P* R ║ GTS            ║
║                ║ <      ║                     ║ G25            ║
║                ║ *      ║ E  L                ║ G2<5           ║
║                ║ @      ║ E  L                ║ G2<5           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ G2<5           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ G21            ║ int(1) ║ L  P@ R             ║ GTS            ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ G21            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ G22            ║ int(2) ║ L  P@ R             ║ GTS            ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ G22            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ G23            ║ int(3) ║ L  P@ R             ║ GTS            ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ G23            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ G24            ║ int(4) ║ L  P@ R             ║ GTS            ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ G24            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ G25            ║ int(5) ║ L  P@ R             ║ GTS            ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ G25            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ GTS            ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ TS             ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ GTS            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ TS             ║ 0      ║                     ║ RL0            ║
║                ║ 1      ║                     ║ RL1            ║
║                ║ e      ║                     ║ RLe            ║
║                ║ x      ║                     ║ RLx            ║
║                ║ None   ║                     ║ RLNone         ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ RL0            ║ @      ║ R  R                ║ GTS0           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ RL0            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ RL1            ║ @      ║ R  R                ║ GTS1           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ RL1            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ RLe            ║ @      ║ R  R                ║ GTSe           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ RLe            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ RLx            ║ @      ║ R  R                ║ GTSx           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ RLx            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ RLNone         ║ @      ║ R  R                ║ GTSNone        ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L                   ║ RLNone         ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ GTS0           ║ 0      ║ R  P*  R            ║ readCommand    ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ GTS0           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ GTS1           ║ 1      ║ R  P*  R            ║ readCommand    ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ GTS1           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ GTSe           ║ e      ║ R  P*  R            ║ readCommand    ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ GTSe           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ GTSx           ║ x      ║ R  P*  R            ║ readCommand    ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ GTSx           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ GTSNone        ║ _      ║ R  P*  R            ║ readCommand    ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ GTSNone        ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ MHP0           ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ Print0         ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ MHP0           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ MHP1           ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ Print1         ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ MHP1           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ MHPe           ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ Printe         ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ MHPe           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ MHPx           ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ Printx         ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ MHPx           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ MHPNone        ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ PrintNone      ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ MHPNone        ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ MHMR           ║ ^      ║ R  R                ║ MHR            ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ MHMR           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ MHML           ║ ^      ║ L                   ║ MHL            ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ MHML           ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ Print0         ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ Print0         ║
║                ║ None   ║ P0                  ║ nextCommand    ║
║                ║ Any    ║ E                   ║ Print0         ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ Print1         ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ Print1         ║
║                ║ None   ║ P1                  ║ nextCommand    ║
║                ║ Any    ║ E                   ║ Print1         ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ Printx         ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ Printx         ║
║                ║ None   ║ Px                  ║ nextCommand    ║
║                ║ Any    ║ E                   ║ Printx         ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ Printe         ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ Printe         ║
║                ║ None   ║ Pe                  ║ nextCommand    ║
║                ║ Any    ║ E                   ║ Printe         ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ PrintNone      ║ ^      ║ R                   ║ PrintNone      ║
║                ║ None   ║                     ║ nextCommand    ║
║                ║ Any    ║ E                   ║ PrintNone      ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ MHL            ║ ^      ║ R  R                ║ MHL            ║
║                ║ [      ║                     ║ SBL            ║
║                ║ Any    ║ L  P^ R  R  E       ║ nextCommand    ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ MHR            ║ ^      ║ R  R                ║ MHR            ║
║                ║ ]      ║                     ║ SBR            ║
║                ║ None   ║ P^ L  L  E          ║ nextCommand    ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ SBR            ║ ]      ║ E  R  R  P]         ║ currentCommand ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ SBL            ║ ]      ║ R                   ║ SBLE           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ R                   ║ SBL            ║
╠----------------╬--------╬---------------------╬----------------╣
║ SBLE           ║ [      ║                     ║ currentCommand ║
║                ║ None   ║ L                   ║ SBLE           ║
║                ║ Any    ║ E  R  R  P] L       ║ SBLE           ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Here is one of Turing's examples from the paper above for my machine:

```
['<', None, 1, '0', None, 'P', 'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', 'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'G', '2',
                      '1', None, 'P', 'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', 'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'G', '2',
                      'e', None, 'P', 'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', 'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'G', '2',
                      'x', None, 'P', 'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', 'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'G', '2',
                      '_', None, 'P', 'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', 'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'G', '2',

             None, 2, '1', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'P', 'x', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'G', '2',
                      '0', None, 'G', '3',

             None, 3, '0', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'G', '3',
                      '1', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'G', '3',
                      '_', None, 'P', '1', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'G', '4',

             None, 4, 'x', None, 'E', 'E', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'G', '3',
                      'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'G', '5',
                      '_', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'G', '4',

             None, 5, '0', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'G', '5',
                      '1', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'G', '5',
                      'e', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'G', '5',
                      'x', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'M', 'R', None, 'G', '5',
                      '_', None, 'P', '0', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'M', 'L', None, 'G', '2',
        None, '[', '^', None, ']', None]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3Z1db9tGGkbv/StY@EKx4yw8X1jAqBdBu4J8QS0EpXeqLDjO68ZYV3JtZTuLor89S1Jf/OYZKjfbXAS2dd4Zzojn4ZCSqOf/rj@vlubr19PofrV8ePwluo7@GHwcXEV//Gu1lKtoNpjI4CIajKfp/4WfLw8/F/4SH/5fDeZ/XpycRod/yZ@StgdqkDa9LfPlsn1xsXbbwmVW@1u16d@ypi9zTW/@/62hIUXJ/VSow9Y9V/t/zvr3WavDYXf/kuv/ob3n/LzU9PzQMPIHPPIHsI3tpKfkfjZrd5dCwZ8nJ@XdcvB91s9Iq2waTnJbcP/l5UWW6x9Xv/56t/yUwpeHuSs9mGxZ1PZP9a7UvStN70rbu9L1rtztbr1q1RG1@ohac0StPaLWHVErR9T6I2oXR9ROj6iNj6idHFE7PqJ2dETt8Ija2RG18yNqb/vXFg9poR2f544yL3L3aV9YOhYsxTccCPKPtHanetToHjWmR43tUeN61BRCnlepXlW6V5XpVWV7VbleVdKryveqWvSqmvaqintVTXpVjXtVjXpVDXtVzXpVzXtV3fapKgYv7@y8ckJTOOk7P/zcFsj5x9Jl/KQ@yCdsPyiXjdmOUC4bsT1hM9ybSTqDbQOb5E/DbpLzm/bD2S4mb5Lzyg5SdqR0kX5H@g5yvzvkxlU/rHE2rG1G3CSz0bEJ8Y6M2yZrlLsQMNLfd06B3pG6izQ70nSRdkfaLtLtSFce02k0Wq1X0fruWaLPyfCih9VLNHu6@yhP8/zQszGWTmBr@8ytVVrmJbc6mbzvVnP004eGhjTqziDKIsohqrD0aOMU5DTkDOQs5BzkBHIecgvIjSE3gtwEcjHkppAbQq5wPOuiiwfNtmbfNzRbjNUsv/IpoFEK6O4UaKH0t8oKg7qziHKIKqeAhimgYQpomAIapoCGKaBhCmiYAhqmgIYpoGEKaJgCGqaAhimgYQrooBTQNAV0UAromhQwhRQwKAUMSgGDDvSmW/HjssKi7hyiyilgYAoYmAIGpoCBKWBgChiYAgamgIEpYGAKGJgCBqaAgSlgYAoYmAImKAUMTQETlAKmJgVsIQUsSgGLUsCiFLDoQG@7FT8uKxzqrpwCFqaAhSlgYQpYmAIWpoCFKWBhCliYAhamgIXWWpgWFqaFhSlgYQrYoBSwNAVsUArYmhRwhRRwKAUcSgGHUsChFHDoQO@6FT8uK8op4GAKOJgCDqaAgyngYAo4mAIOpoCDKeBgCjhot4N2O5gqDqaAgyngglLA0RRwQSnQdBWx9rph/rLh1o6mi4eXgGm4cthonAZtGsBYwDjAFN7n1EwpRGlEGURZRDlECaI8ohaIGiNqgqgRomJETRE1RNQ5ot5XXvBqZPcxcMBKr3ikV/iq@mqgr27Tt53RgYob0KYFjANMSV@N9NVIX4301UhfjfTVSF@N9NVIX4301UhfjfTVSF@N9NVIX4301QH6aqavrtHX1OhrgL4G6GvAEde0KcsVt6BNB5iSvgbpa5C@BulrkL4G6WuQvgbpa5C@BulrkL4G6WuQvgbpa5C@BulrAvQ1TF9To6@t0dcCfS3Q1wJ9LTji2jZlueIOtFnS1yJ9LdLXIn0t0tcifS3S1yJ9LdLXIn0t0tcifS3S1yJ9LdLXIn1tgL6W6Wtr9HU1@jqgrwP6OqCvA/o6cMR1bcpyxUv6OqSvQ/o6pK9D@jqkr0P6OqSvQ/o6pK9D@jqkr0P6OqSvQ/o6pK8L0Ncxfeuuacl688a41/XdWgpmJ3t4YnbeR3L9iZzAkhUwOYQyBxsphSiNKIMoiyiHKEGUR9QCUWNEjRA1QVSMqCmihoiaIeocUbc5qgkqKZpiZUXfpG/JPYt@Olia13Rj6XaPn8b172je7urTuP4i2XZfmsb1713e7kTTuP4Ny7shTOO6d1@fRlNZf3lZRutVFKeXzjfvvs1G8yEdTeFSejqAfehkB92mIeWvoDUyBjAWMA4whVe9mimFKI0ogyiLKIcoQZRH1BRRMaImiBojaoSoIaIWiJohao6oc0TdAqr4AlpzW@8rHytPYuyycqaQhk9ZbQXUVkBtBdRWQG2F1FZIbYXUVkhthdRWSG2F1FZIbYXUVkhthdRWSG2F1FZIbYXUVkhthdRWSG2F1FZIbRWitqpRWypqC1BbgNoC1BagtiC1BaktSG1BagtSW5DagtQWpLYgtQWpLUhtQWoLUluQ2oLUFqS2ILUFqS1IbUFqS4jaUqO2r6jtgdoeqO2B2h6o7ZHaHqntkdoeqe2R2h6p7ZHaHqntkdoeqe2R2h6p7ZHaHqntkdoeqe2R2h6p7ZHaHqntQ9T2NWpn5@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@todv/57mX/a@FyV3Yr0soXRDTfn7T49RAtnIacgZyFnIPcFHIx5CaQG0NOIDeD3BxyI8gNIecZpxClEWUQZRHl2CgXbJRFh9sazL@Dd5JaW31bW3Zv4Bp1FVRXQXUVVFdBdRVUV0F1FVRXQXUVVFdBdRVUV0F1FVRXQXUVVFchdRVSVyF1FVJXIXUVVFdRdRVWV9WpK3XqClRXoLoC1RWorkB1BaorUF2B6gpUV6C6AtUVqK5AdQWqK1BdQeoKUleQuoLUFaSuQHWFqitYXalT19ep66G6Hqrroboequuhuh6q66G6Hqrroboequuhuh6q66G6HqrroboeqeuRuh6p65G6Hqnrobqequuxur5O3f1ltMu6b@9Al4O6aR1EmyDaBtEuiJ4G0XEQPQmix0G0BNGzIHoeRI@C6GEQ7UNoFcDqANYEsDaAdSEzsQiZiUqCdDReyZHad5IVLrL9mv4y@@fji9yvH1fL3Z9K19nG09KH2lu@LkcjyiDKIsohqhSbzZyCnIacgZyFnIPcFHIx5CaQG0JuDLkR5DzkBHIzyM0ht2BcWfrmBm8rbx4d30xrVg7juGpvjOyNkb0xsjdG9sbQ3hjaG0N7Y2hvDO2Nob0xtDeG9sbQ3hjaG0N7Y2hvDO2Nob0xtDeG9sbQ3pjaG3fYu/ma8JvKV8qdTjYvf/3Y@PLX9tJ6ekZQd8W9/TMemzvhdLEqgBXOFr8pvfCNjaXw2l6DrB2jChijChijChij6vpcCGL386HQfEj9fEjAfEjAfEjAfEjAfHR/hmIiaD58/Xz4gPnwAfPhA@bDB8yH754Pj@Zjf6Gg4XwAzwr5ABjGJQz3QfhuhlrmZnPec5Oe9xzOd0rnOXF@2g7J3PJpxw8/xOBztJPb8ndCbAbW@WW1hU/Z9W9Fvkkr/lu0Uvx8FGqmsqCdVvbu3PK35UOnH36Ytm/UdnPiw/@dm3P64fPjwzr64eXu/t@ybtq10p7TbZ43fOfwZF73pfGlgaf7WtpIfmnTuf91UApRgqhbRM2L1LBjQmNJfhl6uf9SvNFeVto9pZtncdNP24lFTf0lq1dN9YrVS1O9sPrbpvpbVr/Zm8q7HvhykO2TlwP/PMn@fZKHzXI1@4Tim/RGiRfR8@r17Cpj0zuZPUePy@wOilf78qziTfJAUhx9d511FsnTq0SDKOlOlp@uB4OzzZ6yYc9yPydMdJ52Er1NpyThspu@RdfR4OPgJLtX43Wy5d8nLaUNX0TqIn3qd78lp0cX6VOx/32cfXoz8PHL5scRHzf/Pkp/14OWq/x/maHIX2co/q8zlMX/4VBOKul1EemLgiy1fXneV@g0XpZQ07CZJmyK9m11x8OxTZV3BNUxGbZhhLY40dnxa9h/s6Sj1KERoae3aUSux3Pmvt1z5npNTmhT/ts1tfiGabX9@yz9@@2Bm29/nJ@kL3g9re6TVcBlskD5@OWX5KefXr7ISWWlsiXPTp7uXjcPRJvVyMnvnx@ftneTTVco6dIt24DT7Rrk5@XPy6zgKlmNvN2Am0XKabKqWa7WUdbzVdTcZwq/ruX5NenzfrV8ePxlljUzn6XgbMvN5/uVVAqni6msaHb1Ts0PS6qk092w/3EdPcky6@0sehepq8KTkv75b8k5TrLIejPLFl5p04@7Rdr87CTfZtrV7HIeXV9nl5UrLe23MhlDxqrDuZA8lRoYlxrYbfDb60jtO1MbdjrYLAjfqWp7GZCsgts3J3sac0PZPB@FkvbnprhaHdQ/2/kd53CH8Nf9X9Jn6t12UvI7RpQsvXPF322rS2vk1m3bbld6s5DcZqWL4p/Xg/O/u@ht7WPLZMX89ev/AA)  (Uses Python 3 as an interpreter) --Edit: I just checked the TIO, and it doesn't seem to actually work right... Try it on your local machine and it should (hopefully) work. It does on mine.

Comment: No harm intended, just aligning the borders on the table.

Comment: @GregBacon No offence taken... perhaps there's some difference between how different computers render codeblocks, but your edit made the alignment much worse on my edit screen... I'm sure it looked fine when you suggested the edit; not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 3):

### Python, <strike>101</strike> <strike>189</strike> <strike>152</strike> 142

```
a=dict(zip(range(len(b)),b))
r=eval(p)
i=s=0
while 1:
 c=a.get(i,' ')
 s,m,a[i]=r[s,c]
 if 0==m:exit([x[1]for x in sorted(a.items())])
 i=i+m
```

b and p are the inputs, b is the initial tape, p encodes the rules as (string representation of) a dict from (in-state, in-tape) tuple to (out-state, head move, out-tape) tuple. If move is 0 the program finishes, 1 is move to the right and -1 is move to the left.

```
b="aaba"

p="""{(0, 'a'): (1, 1, 'a'),
      (0, 'b'): (0, 1, 'b'),
      (1, 'a'): (1, 1, 'a'),
      (1, 'b'): (0, 1, 'b'),
      (1, ' '): (1, 0, 'Y'),
      (0, ' '): (0, 0, 'N')}"""
```

This sample program tests if the last letter of the string (before empty tape) is 'a', if so it writes 'Y' at the end of the string (first empty space).

**Edit 1:**

Changed the tape to be represented as a dict, as it seemed the shortest way to write an extensible data structure. The second to last line is mostly transforming it back into readable form for output.

**Edit 2:**

Thanks to Strigoides for a great deal of improvements.

**Edit 3:**

I had unnecessarily made it so 0 as output would leave the place as it is.
I removed this as we can always write the output the same as the input.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid solution because in your implementation the tape is limited. This way you need to know in advance the memory consumption of your program. And there are problems moving left. Hint: a tape can be made from two modified stack in wich you can always pop a blank symbol.

Comment: Ah, true. Sorry, didn't think this too far.

Comment: Uhm.. afaik the tape is infinite in both direction and you can always read an empty character. I will specify that in the answer.

Comment: You were correct (we had had more strict rules in our exercises). I fixed at least some of the flaws.

Comment: You can remove the space  in the first line, `r=0;s=0` can become `r=s=0` (and the semicolon at the end of that line is unnecessary), you can remove the function `w`, as it is unused, the brackets can be removed in `(s,m,t)=r[s,c]`, the `try`/`except` block can be shortened using dict.get; `c=a.get(i,' ')`, since `m` is either 0 or 1, you can use `if m-1:`, and you can shorten your `map()` call by converting it to a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks! That get was extremely useful knowledge. I have no idea how that w-function was still left in the code, I thought I had removed it long ago. I'm not really that versed with python so your help with the syntax is appreciated too. Only thing is that m can also be -1 if we're moving left, I guess I should give an example of that too.

Answer (score 3):

### APL (110)

(It's not even that short...)

```
0(''⍞){×⍴X←0~⍨⍺∘{x y S T s m t←⍺,⍵⋄S T≡x,⊃⊃⌽y:s,⊂(⊃y){m:(¯1↓⍺)(⍵,⍨¯1↑⍺)⋄(⍺,⊃⍵)(1↓⍵)}t,1↓⊃⌽y⋄0}¨⍵:⍵∇⍨⊃X⋄,/⊃⌽⍺}⎕
```

It reads two lines from the keyboard: the first is the program and the second is the initial tape.

The format is

```
(in-state in-tape out-state movement out-tape)
```

and they should all be on the same line. 'Movement' is 0 to move right and 1 to move left.

Example program (line breaks inserted for clarity, they should be all on one line.)

```
(0 ' ' 1 0 '1')
(0 '1' 0 0 '1')
(1 '1' 1 0 '1')
(1 ' ' 2 1 ' ')
(2 '1' 3 1 ' ')
```

The program adds two unary numbers together, for example:

```
in:  1111 111
out: 1111111
```

Example 2 (adapted from the binary increment program from Marco Martinelli's entry):

```
(0 '0' 0 0 '0')
(0 '1' 0 0 '1')
(0 ' ' 1 1 ' ')
(1 '0' 2 0 '1')
(1 '1' 3 1 '0')
(3 '0' 2 0 '1')
(3 ' ' 2 0 '1')
(3 '1' 3 1 '0')
```

Comment: How can i try it? I'm using linux and tried with aplus but it doesn't work (undefined token :( ). Which interpreter / compiler should I try?

Comment: I'm using Dyalog APL. I'm not aware of using any Dyalog-specific functions but A+ is not completely the same thing. There's a free version of Dyalog but it's only for Windows. (It might run under Wine but it does use its own input method so you can type APL.) If you get Dyalog running, just enter/paste the APL code (on one line), then the Turing machine program (on a second line), then the initial tape (on the third line).

Answer (score 3):

**Postscript <del>(205)</del> <del>(156)</del> <del>(150)</del> (135)**

```
<<
>>begin
/${stopped}def([){add dup{load}${exit}if}def
0 A{1 index{load}${pop( )}if
get{exec}${exit}if}loop
3{-1[pop}loop{1[print}loop
```

This is probably cheating, but the transition table contains code to perform the transitions. And since the tape is represented by a mapping from integers to integers, I've represented states as a mapping from names to dictionaries so the tape and the program coexist in the same anonymous dictionary.

Extra savings by making all state names executable, so they *auto*-load.

Ungolfed with embedded "Hello" program. <del>An extra 52 chars buys a loop to read the tape from stdin.</del> Run with `gsnd -q tm.ps`.

```
%!
<<
    /A<<( ){dup(H)def 1 add B}>>
    /B<<( ){dup(e)def 1 add C}>>
    /C<<( ){dup(l)def 1 add D}>>
    /D<<( ){dup(l)def 1 add E}>>
    /E<<( ){dup(o)def 1 add F}>>
>>begin %ds: int-keys=tape name-keys=prog
0 A %pos state
{ %loop
    1 index{load}stopped{pop( )}if  %pos state tape(pos)
    get    {exec}stopped{exit  }if  %new-pos new-state
} loop
% Loop from tape position 0 to left until left tape end is found
0{                                  %pos
  -1 add                            %new-pos
  dup{load}stopped{exit}if          %new-pos tape(new-pos)
  pop                               %new-pos tape(new-pos)
}loop
% Move to the right and print all chars until right end is hit
{                                   %pos
  1 add                             %new-pos
  dup{load}stopped{exit}if          %new-pos tape(new-pos)
  print                             %new-pos tape(new-pos)
}loop
```

So the table-format is

```
/in-state<<in-tape{dup out-tape def movement add out-state}
           in-tape2{dup out-tape2 def movement2 add out-state2}>>
```

where `in-state` is a name, `in-tape` and `out-tape` are chars (ie. integers, or expressions which yield integers), `movement` is `-1` for left or `1` for right, and `out-state` is an *executable* name. Multiple `in-tape` transition for the same state must be combined as above.

Comment: Another problem is there's no provision for discovering what part of the tape is interesting. That's gonna cost quite a bit to do a `currentdict{search-for-min-and-max}forall juggle-params-for-for`. :(

Comment: Tried my own, but was way beyond your conciseness. But I suggested some improvements to your code.

Comment: BTW, what about the initial tape? I removed the commented out line from the un-golfed code because it didn't seem to do the job. ("0 not" returns -1, therefore no iteration of the loop)

Comment: Excellent improvements! ... About the initial tape code, I think I mistyped it from my notebook. S.B. `0 1 0 not{(%stdin)(r)file read not{exit}if def}for`. I'm not sure why I thought I could get away with omitting that from the golfed version. :P

Comment: Oh, wait, -1! Then `0 not` should be `16#7fffffff`. Sorry. Aha! that's why it was commented! It came straight out of the notebook, didn't get tested, and I trimmed all comments without looking when I golfed it up. *Don't tell the Python guy!* :P

Answer (score 2):

**C (not golfed yet)**

I suppose I can't win with this, still it was fun getting it to work. This is even more true now that it really *does* work. :)

Except it's only infinite in one direction. I suppose it needs a negative tape, too. Sigh....

Negative wasn't so bad. We interleave the two sides as evens and odds. Complication is now it needs to display the tape in *sequential order*, as the file itself is now jumbled. This is a legitimate alteration to make, I think. Turing himself simplified this way.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int c, char**v){
    int min=0,max=0;
    int pos=0,qi;sscanf(v[1],"%d",&qi);
    FILE*tab=fopen(v[2],"r");
    FILE*tape=fopen(v[3],"r+");
    setbuf(tape,NULL);
    do {
        min = pos<min? pos: min;
        max = pos>max? pos: max;
        fseek(tape,(long)(abs(pos)*2)-(pos<0),SEEK_SET);
        int c = fgetc(tape), qt=qi-1,qr;
        fseek(tape,(long)(abs(pos)*2)-(pos<0),SEEK_SET);
        char x = c==EOF?' ':c, xt=x-1,xr,d[2];
        if (x == '\n') x = ' ';
printf("%d '%c' %d (%d)\n", qi, x, pos, (int)ftell(tape));
        while((qt!=qi)||(xt!=x)){
            fscanf(tab, "%d '%c' %d '%c' %1[LRN]", &qt, &xt, &qr, &xr, d);
            if (feof(tab)){
                goto HALT;
            }
printf("%d '%c' %d '%c' %s\n", qt, xt, qr, xr, d);
        }
        qi=qr;
        rewind(tab);
        fputc(xr,tape);
        pos+=*d=='L'?-1:*d=='R'?1:0;
    } while(1);
HALT:
printf("[%d .. %d]:\n", min, max);
    for (pos = min; pos <= max; pos++){
        fseek(tape,(long)(abs(pos)*2)-(pos<0),SEEK_SET);
        //printf("%d ",pos);
        putchar(fgetc(tape));
        //puts("");
    }
    return qi;
}
```

And here's the test-run:

```
522(1)04:33 AM:~ 0> cat bab.tm
0 'a' 0 'b' R
0 'b' 0 'a' R
523(1)04:33 AM:~ 0> echo aaaaa > blank; make tm ; tm 0 bab.tm blank; echo; cat blank
make: `tm' is up to date.
0 'a' 0 (0)
0 'a' 0 'b' R
0 'a' 1 (2)
0 'a' 0 'b' R
0 'a' 2 (4)
0 'a' 0 'b' R
0 ' ' 3 (6)
0 'a' 0 'b' R
0 'b' 0 'a' R
[0 .. 3]:
bbbÿ
babab
```

The program outputs the tape in sequential order, but the file represents the negative and positive sides interleaved.

Comment: There are problems with your implementation. Try this program that swap a and b `0 'a' 0 'b' R; 0 'b' 0 'a' R` with input aaa the output is bab instead of bbb. And there are problems moving left.

Comment: Thanks for the attention! Update fixes both, I think (hope).

Comment: uhm.. still getting bab

Comment: yeah, but this time it's correct! 'aaa' corresponds to positions [0,-1,1] on the tape. But the output that should show this clearly needs work.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy <s>234</s> <s>228</s> <s>154</s> <s>153</s> <s>149</s> <s>139</s> 124

```
n=[:];i=0;t={it.each{n[i++]=it};i=0};e={p,s->a=p[s,n[i]?:' '];if(a){n[i]=a[1];i+=a[2];e(p,a[0])}else n.sort()*.value.join()}
```

Formatted for readability

```
n=[:];
i=0;
t={it.each{n[i++]=it};i=0};
e={p,s->
    a=p[s,n[i]?:' '];
    if(a){
        n[i]=a[1];
        i+=a[2];
        e(p,a[0])
    }else n.sort()*.value.join()
}
```

t is the function that set the tape
e is the function that evaluate the program

Example 1 - Print "Hello!" on the tape :)

```
t('')
e([[0,' ']:[1,'H',1],
   [1,' ']:[2,'e',1],
   [2,' ']:[3,'l',1],
   [3,' ']:[4,'l',1],
   [4,' ']:[5,'o',1],
   [5,' ']:[6,'!',1]],0)
```

Example 2 - Leave a T on the tape if the initial string is in the form of a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>, stop otherwise.

```
t('aaabbb')
e([[0,'a']:[1,' ',1],
   [0,' ']:[4,' ',1],
   [1,'a']:[1,'a',1],
   [1,'b']:[1,'b',1],
   [1,' ']:[2,' ',-1],
   [2,'b']:[3,' ',-1],
   [2,'a']:[5,'a',-1],
   [3,'b']:[3,'b',-1],
   [3,'a']:[3,'a',-1],
   [3,' ']:[0,' ',1],
   [4,' ']:[5,'T',1]],0)
```

Example 3 - Increment of a binary number

```
t('101')
e([[0,'0']:[0,'0',1],
   [0,'1']:[0,'1',1],
   [0,' ']:[1,' ',-1],
   [1,'0']:[2,'1',1],
   [1,'1']:[3,'0',-1],
   [3,'0']:[2,'1',1],
   [3,' ']:[2,'1',1],
   [3,'1']:[3,'0',-1]],0)
```

in the examples 1 means move to the right and -1 means move to the left